# Xcode Error with Crash Symbol Upload: symbolFileUploadLocation: The caller does not have permission

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I followed the guide located here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios

But when I'm done and attempt to build, I get the following error:
/Users/--/Desktop/Test2/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:349: error: symbolFileUploadLocation: The caller does not have permission

Anyone have any ideas?  I've searched on google, stack overflow and google groups and don't see anyone else stating this issue that I can find.

Running 10.11.5, Xcode 7.3.1

When I open the source for the error, it takes you to upload-sym-util.bash, line 349, here is a snippet of that area:

```
    if [[ "$ERRMSG" ]]; then
        if ((VERBOSE)); then
            xcnote "Server response:"
            plutil -p "$FILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION_PLIST" >&2
        fi
        xcerror "symbolFileUploadLocation: $ERRMSG"
        xcnote "symbolFileUploadLocation: Failed to get upload location."
        return 1
    fi
```

Comment: Did you add the ServiceAccount.json to your project?

Comment: Yep, it's in the project and in the file directory.  I echo'd the statement out and validated it is resolving to the correct path.

When I go into the error, it brings up the upload-sum-util.bash ln 349, I added a snippet to my post

Comment: Having the same exact issue.

Comment: I checked "Run script only when installing" in "Run Script" settings and it seems to work. Not sure if this is a right solution.

Comment: Seems like that prevents the script from running all together. So not a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first accept ToS at https://console.cloud.google.com/

Then give editor role to your Service Account created for uploading symbols as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#set_up_crash_reporting

Comment: This did the trick, it resolved this and other errors.  Everything is working great now.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1122778 I am collaborator not the owner of a google.firebase project. but the owner had accepted the ToS (not me, don't have the credit card), but still I am getting the same error. any suggestions please

Comment: Make sure your run script is updated with the correct app id and path to the .json file

Answer (score 4):

There was a mistake in the documentation: steps were omitted. The role of the "Symbol Upload service account" has to have editor privileges to update the symbol database. The following ("step 1½") should have appeared between steps 1 and 2.

> To ensure that the service account has write permission:
>
> 1. On the **Permissions** page, select **IAM** from the left menu.
> 2. Type "Symbol Upload" into the search box.
> 3. The "Symbol Upload service account" must have at least the "Editor" role.

Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either.  If I search for that nothing appears.  If I go to add a new member, i can find it that way, but if I try to grant it Editor Role, then I get an error:

Server Error
There's a problem at our end.

Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using the "Send feedback" link below. Thanks!

Tracking Number: 5827304947654979566

Comment: I got it to work by adding it from Service Account Permissions link. However now when building the app I get a different error.  "Unable to retrieve authentication token from server."

Comment: Still unable to get it to work.  I even tried using one of the already setup accounts and created a key for the Compute service user and tried that (which already was setup to be an editor) and still same error.  I have a feeling something is broken in the service users but I'm not sure if its in my project or in the firebase service itself.  I tried new projects as well and still same issues.

Comment: That you didn't see anything when searching for "Symbol Upload" is troubling. Does the service account exist and have at least one key associated with it?

Comment: I have the same issue Robert. Searching for "Symbol Upload" provides no results. I can find it by lowercase email looking string. However after getting it and trying to set it's permission to Editor an error pops up on Firebase Console that there is an issue on your end.

Comment: FWIW I'm (still) having the same issue as as @sculver2004. I cannot find the "symbol upload service" from the "IAM" section, and adding it as a member directly (using its service account ID) results in a "There's a problem at our end."). In the "Service Accounts" tab I can create a key (which downloads the JSON file), and add the "Editor" to the service acct, but it still doesn't show under "IAM". I took a screencast of the problem, but since there is private info in there, feel free to reach out and I'll send you a link!

Comment: I too have exactly the same problem as @sculver2004.

Comment: Same problem. It's been over a week. And still no solution.

Comment: @sculver2004 did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes. See the answer above. You have to accept the terms of use. They really need to make that part of the normal workflow as there is not way to know that is what is stopping you but following the link in the answer up higher works

Answer (score 4):

let me add to the answers, rename the json file into ServiceAccount.json, drop it into xcode's pods folder and replace google's suggested path with this one, the advantage is the project will be portable if you transfer it to someone else...

```
# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${PODS_ROOT}"/ServiceAccount.json
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure that you give the "Symbol Upload service account" the Project > Editor role **when you create the service account**. The service account will not show up in Permissions > IAM if you neglect to assign a role.
2. When the Xcode run script executes it creates two files int the `$HOME/Library/Preferences/` directory: `com.google.SymbolUpload.plist` and `com.google.SymbolUploadToken.plist`. If you create a new service account (or private key), then you need to delete these two files to wipe out your old service account information. Firebase documentation highlights this, but it deserves repeating.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it is more detailed and complete... Thanks @Jon

Comment: Tried that, did not work - still getting: 

`./Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:351: error: symbolFileUploadLocation: Requests from this ios client application io.fabric.sdk.ios are blocked.
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:352: note: symbolFileUploadLocation: Failed to get upload location.`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me if you add it from **Service Account** screen. Click **Permissions** and add it as an editor.

[image]

Comment: That still didn't work. I think the permissions here are for the service account itself not to firebase project from the sound of the dialogs.  In any event I tried it and didn't change anything, same error

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are confused by the second step of the guide (mentioned in @Robert answer above), you need to be `owner` of the firebase app to change service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when I tried to use a second Firebase database in my project.  However, I forgot that I added crash analytics code to the Run Script that was specific to the first database.  Once I deleted the Run Script code in Build Phases, the problem with the symbol upload file went away.