# Xcode Firebase Crash Reporting Permission denied

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

First: Please don't flag as duplicate since existing threads haven't provided a solution for me.

While trying to [setup the crash reporting API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#set_up_crash_reporting) (FirebaseCrash (1.1.4), for Xcode with Swift 3, I'm getting:

> /xy.sh: line 6: /xyfirebase-crashreporting-xxxxx.json: **Permission denied**

[image]

I have pressed the plus button then "New run script phrase", then I have copy/pasted the `GOOGLE_APP_ID` from my `plist` file and put the json file into the Pods folder.

[image]

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337014/xcode-error-with-crash-symbol-upload-symbolfileuploadlocation-the-caller-does), suggesting to accept the ToS at: https://console.cloud.google.com/
But hitting the link, I can't find any option to accept the ToS, so I guess it's already done?

[image]

Also I have given "editor role"

[image]

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: That permission denied error looks like there is not read access to the json service account file.

Comment: so that i get this right. do you mean the "read permissions" on mac on the file?

Comment: @DougStevenson where do i check the "permissions" you are talking about?

Comment: I would just check the unix style permissions that you see with `ls` and change with `chown` and `chmod`.

Comment: this is the output of `ls -l` = `-rw-r--r--@  1 davidseek  staff   2360 Nov 23 10:48 xy.json`

Comment: tried: `chmod a+r xy.json` , no effect

Comment: besides it looks now differen: `-rw-rw-r--@  1 davidseek  staff   2360 Nov 23 10:48 xy.json`

Comment: I wonder if the PODS_ROOT variable isn't defined for some reason in your project.  Can you try putting the absolute path (without relying on ${PODS_ROOT} as a test to see if that helps?

Comment: sure, i now took the absolut path: `"/Users/davidseek/Desktop/Development/<MYAPP>/Pods/xy.json"` no change. if i change the path to something dumb like `"whatever/xy.json"` it complains, that it can't find the file

Comment: did i setup the editor role collectly IAM @firebase? `Bearbeiter`, german word for editor... and some people have that problem with missing ToS? i can't find any ToS to accept

Comment: try with remove Derived data then run command in terminal 
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*
and play. does this ask any dialog? if yes select your xy.json file

Answer (score 1):

try with

- remove Derived Data then run command in terminal
- `rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*` and
- Play the app.
- select your xy.json file if asked via dialog

if this not work try to change the script like below

```
# Replace this path with the path to the key you just downloaded
#Path/To/ServiceAccount.json
JSON_FILE="$PROJECT_DIR/my_firebase_app_crashreporting-of6c5-07b79d228f.json"

# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:xxxxxxxxxxx:ios:xxxxxxxxxxx

defaults write com.google.SymbolUpload version -integer 1   # creates file if it does not exist
JSON=$(cat "${JSON_FILE}")
/usr/bin/plutil -replace "app_${GOOGLE_APP_ID//:/_}" -json "${JSON}" "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload.plist"
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym
```

Comment: `rm: /Users/davidseek/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*: No such file or directory`

Comment: build successful with your script. does it do the same then?

Comment: receiving a warning: `No service account JSON file specified on command line.`

Comment: does this play the app successfully? try to play/run the app not just build

Comment: uploaded screens for you

Comment: try to crash the app. this will create the crash dump file. on next launch you should see the message successfully upload crash report, or something like that.

Comment: but make sure you run the app without debug mode, i,e disconnect the app from xCode.

Comment: app was running on physical iPhone as well. `fatalError()` in appDelegate resulted in: kinda nothing

Comment: havent seen this: `successfully upload crash report` will run without xcode as suggested now

Comment: app crashed as expected. what to look up for now?

Comment: now remove fatalError() and play the app. you should see successfully upload crash report

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129047/discussion-between-david-seek-and-qadir-hussain).

Comment: @DavidSeek are collaborator of this firebase app or you are the owner?

Comment: I'm the owner of it

Comment: i would like to go back to this try to fix. it at least sent ANY data to firebase. but with missing `symbol file`. maybe we can fix the script or something like that? it's my only hope to ever get that crap done....

Comment: I will award the bounty to you. if I don't no one will get it and that sucks even more. you did NOT help solve my problem and I would like you to try once more.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using an old version of the upload-sym script.  Try updating Firebase Crash.

Comment: ran `pod update Firebase/Crash`, no updates available. `Using FirebaseCrash (1.1.4)`

Comment: added the current version to the question. thank you for your effort. will upvote after bounty period